# Can somebody explain me this proof on Kasch book (Modules and rings)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, proof-explanation

I have a question about one step in the proof of Proposition 13.2.6:

If $R_R$ is injective and ${_R}R$ is noetherian then $R_R$ is a cogenerator and $R$ is artinian on both sides.

In the proof of this Proposition Kasch deduces that:

1. $Rad(R)$ is nilpotent.
2. $\bar{R}=R/Rad(R)$ is regular.
3. $\bar{R}$ is semisimple.

I understand these three points, but the next step is confuse to me. Te next affirmation is "Consequently by 11.6.3, $R$ is perfect on both sides".

The Proposition 11.6.3 is the Bass' Theorem P, thah states that the following conditions are equivalent for a ring $R$:

a) $R$ is right perfect.

b) Every flat right $R$-module is projective.

c) $R$ satisfies the descending chain condition for cyclic left ideals.

d) Every left $R$-module $\neq 0$ possesses a socle $\neq 0$ and $R$ contains no infinite set of orthogonal idempotents.

e) $R/Rad(R)$ is semisimple and $Rad(R)$ is left t-nilpotent.

For Kasch, $R$ is left t-nilpotent if for every family $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ of elements in $R$, exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with
$a_ka_{k-1} \cdots a_1=0$.

Can anybody help me with this, please? Thank you.

Comment: Since the left and right versions of e) are satisfied, the left and right versions of a) should also be satisfied, right?

Answer (score 1):

A nilpotent ideal is $t$-nilpotent on both sides, so the final set of criteria for perfectness applies.

Part of the problem may be reflected in the fact you didn't write the definition of left t-nilpotent correctly. The sequence of elements is taken from within $J(R)$.

Comment: You're right. I just got confused with the definitions of nilpotent and nil ideal.

Comment: @Vandhen  You may already know this, but in general "nilpotent $\implies$ right-left $t$-nilpotent $\implies$ nil" for ideals.